# Insert the header inside another file

Tags: html

How to insert the site header that repeats several times in the site and embed it in the pages where it is needed

I am creating a cinema management site and I would like to put the header and also the footer in a separate file and afterwards put it in the page where I need it since it repeats several times. Which method would you recommend?
I tried php, but I need the html extension, so I can't do it that way. I tried as well with the new HTML5 tag
`<link rel="import" href="mypath.html">`
but it doesn't work.

I found the solution to my problem. I created a file called header.js where I inserted the following code:

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.header')
fetch('../header/header.html')
.then(res=>res.text())
.then(data=>{
  nav.innerHTML=data
})
```

On the main page where the header is to be inserted, I inserted the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cate Cinema</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../page_film/page_film.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css">
  <!-- Font -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Office:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ysabeau+Infant:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Didact+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body id="homepage">
      <header class="header">
        </header>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/header.js">

        </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Instead in the header page I inserted the code inherent to the header itself, without inserting html, in the following way:

```
<nav class="navigation-open">
<div class="global container grid-x">
  <div class="logowrapper grid-x">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-nav cell grid-x">
    <nav class="choicewrapper">
      <ul class="wrapper">
        <li class="page-cinema">
          <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
            <span>A</span>
            <span>l</span>
            <span>&nbsp</span>
            <span>C</span>
            <span>i</span>
            <span>n</span>
            <span>e</span>
            <span>m</span>
            <span>a</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-card">
          <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
            <span>C</span>
            <span>a</span>
            <span>r</span>
            <span>d</span>
            <span>&nbsp</span>
            <span>e</span>
            <span>&nbsp</span>
            <span>P</span>
            <span>r</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>m</span>
            <span>o</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-pass">
          <a href="#" class="gradient-fill-hover">
            <span>P</span>
            <span>a</span>
            <span>s</span>
            <span>s</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <nav class="loginwrapper grid-x cell align-right">
    <div class="form-search-s grid-x">
      <form class="form-search" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" role="search">
        <label for="search">Search for stuff</label>
        <input class="input-search" type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." autofocus required />
        <button type="submit" class="btn-search" onclick="index.html">Go</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-login">
      <a href="../login/login.html" title="Accedi / Registrati">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <span>Login</span>
        <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="container-login open grid-x">
        <div class="dropdown-content grid-x cell">
          <div class="container-dashboard cell d-flex auto">
            <ul>
              <li class="list-login">
                <a href="#" class="login">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                  <span>Login</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="list-login">
                <a href="#" class="registration">
                  <i class="fas fa-square-poll-horizontal"></i>
                  <span>Registrati</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you cannot do it with HTML alone; you need a programming language like PHP or a scripting language like JavaScript

Comment: Which method is more effective, PHP or Javascript? Because if it has to be done with PHP, don't all files need to be given the extension .php? But since I am working locally and I would like to make the pages with html how should I do it?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [ask] page. The question, as written, is too broad.

Comment: Not all files need to have a `.php` extension if you were to choose that way; There is no simple answer as to which is more effective.

Comment: Why do all of your files need to have the `.html` extension??? PHP files work the same way, the only difference being the extension itself and that you can write PHP inside of those files. Oh and any PHP that actually gets executed you need a server to run on.

Comment: If you want to use PHP you must have a server and you must enable it. Because php is a compiled language.

Comment: I don't want to use PHP as a language

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Your main page where you want to include the header -->
<div id="header-placeholder"></div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- Your main content -->
</div>

<!-- Your main script -->
<script>
    // Fetch and insert the header
    fetch('header.html')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById('header-placeholder').innerHTML = data;
        });
</script>
```

If you need to use only js and html, try this way.

Comment: I have tried, but it does not go. The content of the page does not load for me. I checked if it is a file path problem, but it is not that

Comment: Did you check console errors? If it wasn't working you should be getting console errors. Seems like the obvious first thing to look for

Comment: Hi, I finally found a line of code similar to yours, but it gives me problems on path search. The path to my file is: site_cinema/header/header.html and I have to put it inside the folder site_cinema/page_film/test.html. In order to insert it I have to type '../header/header.html', but it gives problems. Would you be able to help me?

Comment: I think your root is site_cinema so it becomes "/header/header.html" inside the fetch function. Your path doesn`t start from c:/etc... but from ***http:// your_site:port/header/header.html***, because there is a server who manages the filesystem.

Comment: Since I am working locally that line of code related to the url as it should be?

Comment: Do you use any server?

Comment: I just realized by looking on the web that I have to install live server where I write the code, as an application I use atom, only I have problems now to install the package "live server". I realized that if I don't install that it can't display the result on chrome

Comment: I suggest using Visual Studio Code, there are several extensions including "live server".

Comment: I used Visual Studio code with the extension, but so this way it is only displayed through the server? If I would like to display it without using a server instead, can't it be displayed?
Isn't there a way to be able to insert the header externally, but have it display without having to use a server?

Comment: I think you're a little confused. So yes, you can use it without a server but only for yourself, to test. In the real world it's different, you need a server to manage the n calls arriving from the web. You can use both the relative path (ex: ../..) and the absolute path (ex: C:/...).

Comment: I know that when I go online it will be different calls, but for now since I am new to this I would like to do it only locally and I wanted to look for a local-only method.
I tried to do it as described in the other comments, only it doesn't read me the path to the file I'm going to insert and I don't understand why.